# Несколько кнопок, только одна нажатая меняет стиль

Tags: python, pyqt, qss, qpushbutton, pyside6

Есть несколько кнопок. 
Надо сделать "*Только нажатая меняет стиль - становится другого цвета*". 
Нажатой может быть только одна кнопка.

Понимаю, что это делается через `toggle` + `isChecked`, но запутался.

```
import sys        
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.someFunction()

    def someFunction(self):
        for i in range(3):
            button = QPushButton("Button {}".format(i), self)
            button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
            self.layout.addWidget(button)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        btn = self.sender()
        btn.setStyleSheet("background-color : blue")


if __name__ == '__main__':        
    app = QApplication([])
    mainapp = MainWindow()
    mainapp.show()
    app.exec()
```

В примере стоит `PySide`, это тот же `PyQt`, можно просто заменить в импортах одно на другое.

Comment: во первых, поправьте отступы в примере который вы дали

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте в инициализации список для хранения ссылок на данные кнопки. При создании кнопок, добавьте кнопку в этот список. При нажатии проверяйтесь циклом по списку, если кнопка из списка совпадает с той, которую вы нажали, меняйте стиль, иначе сбрасывайте его. Делал на примере `PyQt6`

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
import sys

class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.buttons = []  # Создаем список для хранения кнопок
        self.someFunction()

    def someFunction(self):
        for i in range(3):
            button = QPushButton("Button {}".format(i), self)
            button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
            self.layout.addWidget(button)
            self.buttons.append(button)  # Добавляем кнопку в список

    def buttonClicked(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        for btn in self.buttons:
            if btn is sender:
                btn.setStyleSheet("background-color : blue")
            else:
                btn.setStyleSheet("")  # Сбрасываем стиль для остальных кнопок

if __name__ == '__main__':        
    app = QApplication([])
    mainapp = MainWindow()
    mainapp.show()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант:

- [**autoExclusive**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractbutton.html#autoExclusive-prop) : bool
  Если включена автоматическая эксклюзивность, проверяемые кнопки, принадлежащие одному и тому же родительскому виджету, ведут себя так, как если бы они были частью одной и той же группы эксклюзивных кнопок.
- [**checkable**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractbutton.html#checkable-prop) : bool
  Это свойство определяет, доступна ли кнопка для проверки.

---

```
import sys
'''
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *
'''
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.someFunction()

    def someFunction(self):
        for i in range(3):
            button = QPushButton("Button {}".format(i), self)
            button.setAutoExclusive(True)                             # !!! +++
            button.setCheckable(True)                                 # !!! +++
            button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
            self.layout.addWidget(button)

    def buttonClicked(self, state):
        buttons =  self.findChildren(QPushButton)                     # !!! +++
        for btn in buttons:
            if  btn.isChecked():
                btn.setStyleSheet("background-color : blue")
            else:
                btn.setStyleSheet("")
                

if __name__ == '__main__':        
    app = QApplication([])
    mainapp = MainWindow()
    mainapp.show()
    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Создал собственный класс ToggleButton, который наследует от QPushButton. Он имеет сигнал button_toggled, который отправляет сигнал при каждом переключении кнопки.

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *

# Создаем кастомный класс ToggleButton, который наследует от QPushButton
class ToggleButton(QPushButton):
    # Создаем сигнал для оповещения о переключении кнопки
    button_toggled = Signal(bool)

    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__(text)
        self.setCheckable(True)  # Делаем кнопку переключаемой (toggleable)
        self.clicked.connect(self.handle_toggle)  # Подключаем обработчик события нажатия

    def handle_toggle(self):
        self.button_toggled.emit(self.isChecked())  # Отправляем сигнал с текущим состоянием кнопки

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.button_group = []  # Список для хранения кнопок
        self.someFunction()

    def someFunction(self):
        for i in range(3):
            button = ToggleButton("Button {}".format(i))  # Используем кастомный ToggleButton
            button.button_toggled.connect(self.buttonToggled)  # Подключаем обработчик переключения кнопки
            self.layout.addWidget(button)
            self.button_group.append(button)

    def buttonToggled(self, checked_button):
        # Перебираем все кнопки в группе
        for button in self.button_group:
            if button is not checked_button:
                button.setChecked(False)  # Сбрасываем состояние всех кнопок, кроме выбранной
                button.setStyleSheet("")  # Сбрасываем стиль
            else:
                button.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue")  # Устанавливаем стиль для выбранной кнопки

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    mainapp = MainWindow()
    mainapp.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: спасибо за участие, но новый класс - это переусложнение

Comment: Данный [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1543621/568135) получился верным, но раз открыл, решил предложить альтернативный метод =)